# SVG Hover Doesn´t Work changing the colour of the arrow icon when put the mouse over the Video

Tags: svg, hover

**When i put the video and then an SVG Icon. The Hover not working:**
** The icon is over the video **

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Nombre Stand</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="css/agency.min.css" rel="stylesheet">




<style>


svg{

  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 80px ;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  fill: none;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:10%;
    height:10%;
    position:absolute;
    left:75%;
    right:0%;
    top:55%;
    bottom:0%;
    margin:auto;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position: center;

    
    }


svg:hover #izq {

 fill: #DA4567;
    

}


 
</style>


</head>




<body>


  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   width="40px" height="40px" viewBox="0 0 40 40" enable-background="new 0 0 40 40" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
  <path id="izq" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#F5BA1D" d="M32.337,33.807c-1.199-2.181-2.847-3.623-4.188-5.305
    c-2.059-2.582-4.243-5.062-6.429-7.534c-0.688-0.779-0.153-1.097,0.28-1.612c3.306-3.923,6.586-7.87,9.88-11.802
    c0.228-0.271,0.608-0.499,0.476-0.892c-0.18-0.533-0.696-0.267-1.069-0.338c-0.057-0.011-0.12,0.008-0.175-0.004
    c-3.144-0.702-5.203,0.831-7.066,3.272c-2.575,3.376-5.369,6.578-8.127,9.802c-0.585,0.684-0.667,1.042-0.04,1.771
    c3.341,3.887,6.613,7.838,9.914,11.762c0.386,0.458,0.795,0.885,1.46,0.881C28.873,33.801,30.491,33.807,32.337,33.807z"/>
  <path id="izq" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#F5BA1D" d="M21.628,33.815c-2.317-2.749-4.283-5.09-6.26-7.421
    c-1.563-1.841-3.121-3.687-4.722-5.493c-0.627-0.707-0.091-1.017,0.292-1.473c3.341-3.967,6.666-7.948,10-11.921
    c0.224-0.267,0.603-0.477,0.45-0.891c-0.162-0.437-0.596-0.281-0.92-0.286c-1.23-0.019-2.467,0.064-3.691-0.027
    c-1.119-0.083-1.522,0.829-2.054,1.452c-3.248,3.811-6.403,7.705-9.667,11.5c-0.681,0.792-0.822,1.169-0.064,2.028
    c3.272,3.712,6.494,7.474,9.623,11.314c0.682,0.836,1.291,1.267,2.322,1.229C18.329,33.777,19.724,33.815,21.628,33.815z"/>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>

  </a>



<div id="video1">
    <video id="myVideoder" width="100%" height="100%">
           <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/ocean-small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>


      
 <!--<body background="img/Stand.png" id="fondo"> -->


  <!-- Header 
  <header>
   
  </header>



 

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
  <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Contact form JavaScript -->
  <script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
  <script src="js/contact_me.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
  <script src="js/agency.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**The SVG Icon: The code is simplified . The Id called "izq" **

```
<a href="#" target="_blank">
    <svg ........
  <path **id="izq"** d="M32.337,33............ 
}</a>
```

**The SVG .CSS**

```
svg{

    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 80px ;
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    fill: none;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position: center;

    }
```

This is the .CSS Hover Code

```
svg:hover #izq {

 fill: #DA4567;
 position:absolute;
 display: inline-block;
 background-size:contain;
    

}
```

I add the video Example:

**OVER THE IMAGE - ITS OK!!**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4PHMMrr23Qw

**OVER THE VIDEO - THE OVER DOESNT WORK:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NzmcER9q2j8

share  edit  delete  flag

Comment: Please upload [mcve] somewhere so we can see the problem in action.

Comment: Note most of your #izq CSS has no effect. `position` and `background` have no effect on elements inside an SVG. The `display` is probably not doing anything either.

Answer (score 0):

The `<video>` element is after the `<svg>` in your HTML.  If you don't change the order somehow, it will capture the mouse events.  Either:

1. Reorder the elements in the file so that the `<a>` is after the `<video>` (see below), or
2. Specify that the SVG should be on top by giving it a `z-index` > 0.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Nombre Stand</title>

<style>


svg {
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 80px ;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  fill: none;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:10%;
  height:10%;
  position:absolute;
  left:75%;
  right:0%;
  top:55%;
  bottom:0%;
  margin:auto;
}

svg:hover #izq {
  fill: #DA4567;
}

</style>
</head>


<body>

  <div id="video1">
    <video id="myVideoder" width="100%" height="100%">
      <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/ocean-small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>

  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   width="40px" height="40px" viewBox="0 0 40 40" enable-background="new 0 0 40 40" xml:space="preserve">
      <g>
        <path id="izq" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#F5BA1D" d="M32.337,33.807c-1.199-2.181-2.847-3.623-4.188-5.305
    c-2.059-2.582-4.243-5.062-6.429-7.534c-0.688-0.779-0.153-1.097,0.28-1.612c3.306-3.923,6.586-7.87,9.88-11.802
    c0.228-0.271,0.608-0.499,0.476-0.892c-0.18-0.533-0.696-0.267-1.069-0.338c-0.057-0.011-0.12,0.008-0.175-0.004
    c-3.144-0.702-5.203,0.831-7.066,3.272c-2.575,3.376-5.369,6.578-8.127,9.802c-0.585,0.684-0.667,1.042-0.04,1.771
    c3.341,3.887,6.613,7.838,9.914,11.762c0.386,0.458,0.795,0.885,1.46,0.881C28.873,33.801,30.491,33.807,32.337,33.807z"/>
        <path id="izq" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#F5BA1D" d="M21.628,33.815c-2.317-2.749-4.283-5.09-6.26-7.421
    c-1.563-1.841-3.121-3.687-4.722-5.493c-0.627-0.707-0.091-1.017,0.292-1.473c3.341-3.967,6.666-7.948,10-11.921
    c0.224-0.267,0.603-0.477,0.45-0.891c-0.162-0.437-0.596-0.281-0.92-0.286c-1.23-0.019-2.467,0.064-3.691-0.027
    c-1.119-0.083-1.522,0.829-2.054,1.452c-3.248,3.811-6.403,7.705-9.667,11.5c-0.681,0.792-0.822,1.169-0.064,2.028
    c3.272,3.712,6.494,7.474,9.623,11.314c0.682,0.836,1.291,1.267,2.322,1.229C18.329,33.777,19.724,33.815,21.628,33.815z"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </a>

</body>

</html>
```